# adding weight to each random object picker

Tags: javascript

Here is the code where I want to randomly pick a city from the **liste**, based on its weight and then modify weights based on the distance between cities( more distance with picked city results in more weight). after this again I use the **modified liste** to randomly pick another city.
the code is working fine except one thing...

here is the code:

```js
// list of cities
var liste = [
   { name: "New York", distance: 12, weight: 5, mainweight: 5},
   { name: "Atlanta", distance: 4, weight: 4, mainweight: 4},
   { name: "Dallas", distance: 2, weight: 2, mainweight: 2},
   { name: "Los Angeles", distance: 1, weight: 1, mainweight: 1},
];;

var repeatTimes = 4;
var choose = [];
choose = [liste.map(x=>x.name), liste.map(x=>x.distance), liste.map(x=>x.weight)];

// randomaly pick a city based on its weight
var rand = function(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

var getRandomItem = function(choose, weight) {

    var total_weight = weight.reduce(function (prev, cur, i, arr) {
        return prev + cur;
    });

    var random_num = rand(0, total_weight);
    var weight_sum = 0;
    //console.log(random_num)

    for (var i = 0; i < choose.length; i++) {
        weight_sum += weight[i];
        weight_sum = +weight_sum.toFixed(2);

        if (random_num <= weight_sum) {
            return choose[i];
        }
    }
    // end of function, modify the weights of list again
        
};

  // for the first time pick a city randomaly
  var random_item = getRandomItem(choose[0], choose[2]);
  console.log(random_item);

 newWeights();

// after the first time of picking cities let's modify the weights of list
function newWeights(){
var baseDistance = liste.find(l => l.name == random_item).distance;
  
//console.log(liste[choose[0].indexOf(random_item)].distance);
 
var list = liste.map(c => {
  var newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance);
  
    if(newWeight !== 0){
   var newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance) + c.mainweight;
       return {
    name: c.name,
    distance: c.distance,
    weight: newWeight
  };
}
  
  return {
    name: c.name,
    distance: c.distance,
    weight: newWeight
  };
 
});  
liste = list.filter(function(value){

    return value.weight != 0;

});  
choose = [liste.map(x=>x.name), liste.map(x=>x.distance), liste.map(x=>x.weight)];
console.log(liste);
}

// use the modified list to randomaly picking another city
 for (var i = 1; i < repeatTimes; i++) {     
   
       var random_item = getRandomItem(choose[0], choose[2]);
       console.log(random_item);   
        newWeights();
 }
```

Here is where I create list array which holds the modified liste.

```
var list = liste.map(c => {
  var newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance);
  return {
    name: c.name,
    distance: c.distance,
    weight: newWeight
  };

});
```

All I want is adding **weight** of each object to **newWeight** like this:

```
if(newWeight !== 0){
var newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance) + c.weight;
}
```

But each time I get errors.

Comment: Please be more specific that just saying "I get errors".  Your code snippet runs.

Comment: hello again! On to the next step I see. The code you say produces errors is not in your code samples (specifically the `if`) statement. Please edit the snippet to show us where that code exists when it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(newWeight !== 0){
   var newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance) + c.weight;
}
```

In that code, you're checking `newWeight`, then initializing `newWeight` which may be your error. Assuming you already set `newWeight` before this code, remove `var`

```
if(newWeight !== 0){
   newWeight = Math.abs(baseDistance - c.distance) + c.weight;
}
```

or if you meant to assign it to another variable, update it to match what you meant.